How many times and who could actually enter the Kodesh HaKodashim?
Is it technically true that only the Kohen Gadol would enter the Kodesh HaKodashim only once a year?
When the Mishkan traveled, the Kohanim (seemingly more than one) needed to also enter to cover the Ark. And then did the Leviyim need to also enter to lift it?
(Perhaps the Mishkan structure was dismantled before the Ark was covered and thus technically there was no longer a Kodesh Kodashim area to enter. But that seems unlikely since that would make the Ark visible from the outside)

If I'm not mistaken, in the Mikdash repairmen were lowered into the KH"K in wooden boxes.

I think the vilna gaon learns a novel reading from the pesukim in acharey mos. That when the Torah says "bezos yovoy aharon el hakodesh" only with the following sacrifices is aharon allowed into the kodesh hakodoshim, most learn that these sacrifices are specific to once a year on yom Kippur however the gra learns that the kohen godol is allowed to come into the kodesh kodoshim any time of the year with these sacrifices.   Unfortunately I have no source for this...

I heard this in a shiur once too... somewhere in the second half of masechet yoma. No source either!
